# web.config is invalid after publishing my Core 2.2 project on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a project written using C# on the top of Asp.NET Core 2.2 framework.

I was able to publish it to my VPS. But, when I try to access the website I get the following error

> **HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Here is the content of the web.config file located in the root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ProjectName.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 47b26df0-8a01-4d75-9549-3a98654550a3-->
```

The `web.config` file was published via Visual Studio along with the rest of my files. But I don't see `web.config` file in my solution.

This file seems to be invalid. How can I fix the web.config file?

If I remove the `web.config` file and add `index.html` page the site work. It sounds to me that `web.config` the file is invalid for some reason.

**Updated**
I am able to run the application using the command line. 
using the command line, I did the following

1. I change directory into the root of my website (i.e `cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ProjectName`)
2. I execute the following command `dotnet ProjectName.dll`
3. 10 seconds later, I got some information that the app is running and it showed me the URL it is listing to. In my case it was http://localhost:5000
4. O used the browser to browser http://localhost:5000 and it works fine.

But when I access it using the domain name, I still get Http Error 500.19 as stated above.

Comment: Is the `web.config` file copied to output directory?

Comment: @swdon yes it does. In fact, I am able to start the project using the command line. I'll update my question with explanation

Comment: Please post your server side log for this error as well.

Comment: are you targeting .net core or .net framework?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `<location>` element?

Comment: Btw if you are publishing to VPS did you install asp.netcore module on iis?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat no I did not. I just installed the Microsoft Core 2.2.1 after downloading it from here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.2.1-windows-hosting-bundle-installer  what other steps that are needed after the installation?

Comment: I think iis reset would be all you need to do.

Comment: I am targeting asp.net core 2.2.1

Comment: Yes i see you have dll :) does it work after installation of moduole?

Comment: Well that error is gone. I can't belive a silly step "restart" fixed it.  The new error I get "An error occurred while processing your request.  Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application. "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in comments

Install AspnetCore module in iis

Setup ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to production in your environment or
setup in [web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#setting-environment-variables).

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
      arguments=".\MyApp.dll"
      stdoutLogEnabled="false"
      stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout"
      hostingModel="InProcess">
  <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
  </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

Comment: It seems to be using the appsettings.developement.json instead of appsettings.production.json in production. Any idea why would that be?

Comment: @MikeA I would look in startup.cs how you are bootstraping config

Comment: I am not doing anything extra to boot a specific settings file.  It is my understanding the the app should automatically load the proper settings based on the environment name

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your help